# What scripting frameworks exist for database-based reporting?

Tags: java, database, scripting, jasper-reports, reporting

I have to run a lot of relational-database-based reports for my job. In order to make my life easier, I have written a handful of scripts and programs to run a report (simple SQL query, complicated super-specific cross-cutting query, and full JasperReports anything-goes-style reports), compress and/or encrypt it, and deliver it via SMTP to one or more recipients.

Some of this has been written in Java, some in PHP, and some as bash shell scripts. I'd like to unify a lot of this, plus add a single report-description format that can include configuration information like which report (or reports: sometimes I have to run several reports at once and combine them into a single "package" for the client) to run, what any parameters for the report should be set to (customer id, for instance), who should receive the report via email/SFTP/etc.

Note that tools like JasperReports are only part of the solution: the actual report-generation part. I'm more interested in something that can be used to script the whole process and be run from a cron job.

Do any products (OSS would be great) exist to help me with this kind of thing? Or, is this kind of thing so unique to a particular environment as to require the kind of customized tools that I have already built?

Comment: Not trying to be difficult, but why not just simple java apps that use jasperreports, and simple scripts to that call them to set up cron jobs for? Other than that, I believe JasperServer has the ability to set up automated reporting, but it may be overkill for what you are doing.

Comment: @jschoen That's exactly what I have right now, but I'm finding that I need more and more features, and I want to make it easier for non-programmers to submit reports (say, in XML format). If there was something out there that existed already, I would rather use that than continue to work with my hacked-together system of utilities and scripts.

Comment: Did you take a look at JasperServer?

Comment: I'm checking-out JasperServer, which I knew existed. I didn't realize that it had some of the features it does (scheduled reporting, delivery, etc). I'm sure I will need some additional features above and beyond what it supports, but it might be a good starting point. I'll take a look this week.

Comment: Okay, I read a lot about JasperServer, installed it and played-around with it but it still lacks some features that I really need: decent compression and encryption of reports (WinZIP-style AES-256 or PGP for instance), bundling of multiple reports into a single communication, executing a report multiple times across different segments of customers, SFTP delivery, etc. My existing setup allows me to do everything above conveniently except the two batching things, SFTP, and PGP. I was hoping to find something that could support such things instead of continuing to build a custom solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) that integrates with your Java/J2EE application to produce compelling reports. And the second option is [DataVision](http://datavision.sourceforge.net/) that is similar to popular Crystal Reports.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not having any problem creating the reports: it's the packaging, delivery, scheduling, etc. that I want.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little off what you were thinking about, but have you considered (or heard of) [R](http://www.r-project.org/) ?  R is an open source statistical programming language that has many features, but specific to your problems is;

- Is open source
- Has packages that enable interacting with SQL databases (generic ODBC, or specific Oracle, MySQL, Postgres etc)
- Can do many kinds of data processing steps with the data
- Can produce
  tables and graphs
- Can produce documents in several ways ([LaTex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweave),
  Markdown, ODF)
- Can be used from the command line, (for instance I
  produce documents with make)
- Can be integrated into a web server
  ([RApache](http://www.rapache.net/))
- Can run Java code ([RJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/))

the only problem is this would be roll your own, there's no specific implementation that offers the features you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I have no problem creating the reports themselves: what I'm looking for is something that will let me run them, package them, and deliver them.

Answer (score 0):

some frameworks that might help you with configuring report delivery workflow are.

1. Apache Service Mix http://servicemix.apache.org/ see achitecture diagram froma a previous version http://servicemix.apache.org/home.data/ServiceMix3.png
2. Spring integration http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/

Both should give you a framework for building a decoupled architecture so that the part does report compression and the part that does report encryption and report generation don't know about each other but can be configured via the framework to work in a particular workflow.

Comment: ASM is very Web-Services oriented and really doesn't include any single tool that I can use. Spring is also not terribly helpful as it is intended for integration, IOC, etc. I can certainly build my own decoupled architecture: in fact, I'm already doing it. I was hoping that something more useful than 'bash' would be out there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check Gradle http://www.gradle.org/. Since it is based on Groovy you can send Mails, package archives and call JasperReports easily.

From Gradle web site:

> Gradle is build automation evolved. Gradle can automate the building,
>   testing, publishing, deployment and more of software packages or other
>   types of projects such as generated static websites, generated
>   documentation or indeed anything else.
>
> Gradle combines the power and flexibility of Ant with the dependency
>   management and conventions of Maven into a more effective way to
>   build. Powered by a Groovy DSL and packed with innovation, Gradle
>   provides a declarative way to describe all kinds of builds through
>   sensible defaults. Gradle is quickly becoming the build system of
>   choice for many open source projects, leading edge enterprises and
>   legacy automation challenges.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Pentaho: http://www.pentaho.com/explore/pentaho-business-analytics/